# How to submit the next option in a select with javascript,jquery, or some other clever way?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php page that i would like to add a NEXT SELECTION feature to my select.

Here is my code:

```
<form action='' method='GET' id='searchSelect'>
   <select name='search'>
      <option>beer</option>
      <option>chips</option>
      <option selected>BACON</option>
      <option>CHEESE</option>
      <option>poutine</option>
   </select>
   <input type='submit'>
   <button>NEXT SELECTION</button>
</form>
```

I feel like i should be able to focus the selected (in this case BACON) and submit it(CHEESE) with JavaScript with the button but i am unsure how to implement this correctly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[a FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wdx34Ljt/3/)

EDIT: To clarify my problem: I have a long long list in my select, when going through the choices its a pain to re-select the option bar and choose the next option in the list. I want the user to be able to click next, and it would submit the next in the list after the current SELECTED option. The page is php and when click it submits with the GET method to the current page. When the page is loaded it grabs the GET(name=search)and sets it to selected with some php on the page.

Comment: What you need to do? Send some data to another page (you can then delete the submit button and use Javascript Ajax) and then?

Comment: place your steps inside some containers like div .. they can be inside form .. on step 1 next button click hide step 1 .. show step 2 .. and so on and on last step have the submit button instead of next ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery (simplified):

```
$("select").find("option:selected").next().prop("selected",true);
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdx34Ljt/4/) (`e.preventDefault()` is to show that value changed - to submit remove that line)

**UPDATE**

Used `:selected` instead of `[selected]` to get currently selected option, and not original selected..

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdx34Ljt/5/)

Comment: This jQuery answer seems to be the most fitting for what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may code this where ever you needed, in this case on submit

**JavaScript:**

```
function selectNext(){
  document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex + 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="selectNext()">Next</button>
```

Pure javascript code.

Comment: jQuery to this: `$("#mySelect")[0].selectedIndex += 1;`

Comment: I did put jquery in the title but not explicitly the description. jquery or some other way was just fine.

Comment: @AshiqueCM, Question Title: `...javascript,jquery, or some other clever way?...`